# Sort three models by date, in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have for example three 'models':

```
Letter

  text:string
  caption:string
  date:date

Application

  name:string
  text:string
  date:date

Newspaper

  title:string
  text:string
  date:date
```

How you can see each model has an text and an date!
So is it possible to  sort the three models by date and the coressponding text, so that it looks like this?

```
12.09.2013 Newspaper-text
13.09.2013 Appliction-text
13.09.2013 Letter-text
14.09.2013 Newspaper-text
```

I hope you can understand my issue! And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose you've collected each set of model data with the desired filtering conditions into it's own array: `@newspapers`, `@applications`, and `@letters`. Then you'd do something like this:

```
(@newspapers + @applications + @letters).sort_by(&:date).each do |item|
   <%= item.date %>
   <%= item.text %> 
end
```

Comment: @acts_as_geek heh yeah just lucky.